# Python: moving file to a newly created directory

Tags: python, filesystems, shutil

I've got my script creating a bunch of files (size varies depending on inputs) and I want to be certain files in certain folders based on the filenames.

So far I've got the following but although directories are being created no files are being moved, I'm not sure if the logic in the final for loop makes any sense.

In the below code I'm trying to move all .png files ending in _01 into the sub_frame_0 folder.

Additionally is their someway to increment both the file endings _01 to _02 etc., and the destn folder ie. from sub_frame_0 to sub_frame_1 to sub_frame_2 and so on.

```
for index, i in enumerate(range(num_sub_frames+10)):
    path = os.makedirs('./sub_frame_{}'.format(index))

# Slice layers into sub-frames and add to appropriate directory

list_of_files = glob.glob('*.tif')
for fname in list_of_files: 
    image_slicer.slice(fname, num_sub_frames) # Slices the .tif frames into .png sub-frames

list_of_sub_frames = glob.glob('*.png')
for i in list_of_sub_frames:
    if i == '*_01.png':
        shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '*_01.png'), './sub_frame_0/')
```

Comment: Are you trying to move a file called `[path]\*_01.png` ?

Comment: Have you checked for the names of the files you are trying to move? File names cannot contain '*'.

Comment: `i == '*_01.png'` is a literal search (i.e. i must be exactly `'*_01.png'` for it to work). It will not glob the files if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: In fact, `if i == '*_01.png':` does not make sense. `i` will contain an actual file name which I suppose will not be '*_01.png'.

Comment: @MichalFrystacky I'm trying to move all files ending with _01.png.

Comment: @UrielEli yes and I need to enforce regepxs

Comment: @FamousJameous I'd love to be able to glob here

Comment: @BenBeirut as suggested below I'll try implement regexps

Comment: Use matches. Your current code just tries to check for that specific string.

Comment: @BenBeirut, I'm still a noob so I'm not sure how to do that, let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to check if '*_01.png' is in the file name `i` and change the `shutil.move` to include `i`, the filename. (It's also worth mentioning that `i`is not a good name for a filepath

```
list_of_sub_frames = glob.glob('*.png')
for i in list_of_sub_frames:
    if '*_01.png' in i:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i), './sub_frame_0/')
```

> Additionally is [there some way] to increment both the file endings _01 to _02 etc., and the destn folder ie. from sub_frame_0 to sub_frame_1 to sub_frame_2 and so on.

You could create file names doing something as simple as this:

```
for i in range(10):
    #simple string parsing
    file_name = 'sub_frame_'+str(i)
    folder_name = 'folder_sub_frame_'+str(i)
```

Comment: @vanoccupanther I am glad it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the logic of the final loop does not make sense.

```
if i == '*_01.ng'
```

It would evaluate something like `'image_01.png' == '*_01.png'` and be always false.

Regexp should be the way to go, but for this simple case you just can slice the number from the file name.

```
for i in list_of_sub_frames:
    frame = int(i[-6:-4]) - 1
    shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i), './sub_frame_{}/'.format(frame))
```

If `i = 'image_01.png'` then `i[-6:-4]` would take '01', convert it to integer and then just subtract 1 to follow your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example using regular expressions. This also implements the incrementing of file names/destination folders

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import re

num_sub_frames = 3
# No need to enumerate range list without start or step
for index in range(num_sub_frames+10):
    path = os.makedirs('./sub_frame_{0:02}'.format(index))

# Slice layers into sub-frames and add to appropriate directory

list_of_files = glob.glob('*.tif')
for fname in list_of_files:
    image_slicer.slice(fname, num_sub_frames) # Slices the .tif frames into .png sub-frames

list_of_sub_frames = glob.glob('*.png')
for name in list_of_sub_frames:
    m = re.search('(?P<fname>.+?)_(?P<num>\d+).png', name)
    if m:
        num = int(m.group('num'))+1
        newname = '{0}_{1:02}.png'.format(m.group('fname'), num)
        newpath = os.path.join('./sub_frame_{0:02}/'.format(num), newname)
        print m.group() + ' -> ' + newpath
        shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), m.group()), newpath)
```